# How to force update HTML's TextArea element?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Sorry for newbie question but it's related to WebKit issue. I have the next JS code:

```
var Module = {
        preRun: [],
        postRun: [],
        print: (function() {
          var element = document.getElementById('output');
          if (element) element.value = ''; // clear browser cache
          return function(text) {
            text = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
            // These replacements are necessary if you render to raw HTML
            //text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
            //text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
            //text = text.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
            //text = text.replace('\n', '<br>', 'g');
            console.log(text);
            if (element) {
              element.value += text + "\n";
              console.log('updated element.value');
              element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight; // focus on bottom
            }
          };
        })
```

element is textarea element:

```
<textarea id="output" rows="8"></textarea>
```

I have code that printf using that function and then shows prompt to type user name.
So i expect to see 'updated element.value' in browser console and printed text in `textarea` before prompt dialog is shown.

How can i force `textarea` to refresh after it's changed (`element.value += text + "\n"`)?

It works as expected in chrome/firefox but fails in Safari(WebKit) - i can't see output at the moment prompt dialog is shown.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like something that can't be done, but there might be Webkit specific hacks I'm not aware about. Maybe all browsers do both updates during the same render cycle which you'd expect, but Safari displays the prompt first and somehow pauses the remaining updates until the prompt is dismissed.

The most obvious workaround is something like

```
print('lorem ipsum');
setTimeout(function(){
    var response = prompt('my question here');
    //handle the response
}, 10);
```

which is likely to guarantee that the textarea update happens before the prompt locks things.

Comment: this is not desired as it breaks instructions flow and start concurrent execution in another thread with delay. i'm not sure how to return value from background (delayed code)

Comment: Yeah, it easily becomes a mess and should only be a last resort :(. You can't really return from the delayed code but have to split your logic into an "after" chunk which you can invoke from the "prompt thread" I guess.